# Элемент с раскрывающимся списком wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Доброго дня.

Как в wpf реализовать вывод дисков и папок в таком виде, как на картинке(прикрепил к вопросу). Как вообще этот элемент называется в XAML?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx), не?

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/treeviewadv/images-for-items-in-treeviewadv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Называется TreeView. Тут есть неплохой [материал](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level22/22_5.php). 
Если интересуют более функциональные решения, могу посоветовать компонент от Telerik - [RadTreeView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treeview.aspx), он поддерживает виртуализацию.

Comment: В Telerik мне цена [понравилась](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/individual/wpf.aspx) $999 за комплект для WPF